# How to do Digital to Analogue Conversion in Simulink?

Tags: simulink

I am building a Polyphase filter in Simulink and have reached a point where I need to do a Digital to Analogue conversion at the output.

I assumed there was a DAC converter block in Simulink but I cannot seem to find it.

My question is, how do I build my own DAC in simulink?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what do you want to do and what your source signal is. What kind of behaviour do you want to simulate:

- Conversion delay? --> delay block
- Quantisation... so you will have a integer signa (the Digital part of it) and then convert it to double and scale it to the correct voltage --> a gain block
- Noise? --> add some bits of random numbers to the integer signal
- You also might need to change sample rate (fixed rate on the Digital side to continuous in the analogue side)
- You will need to add a low pass filter to simulate the settling time as well